# Cannot reference findViewbyId() even when using Context

Tags: android

In my oncreate method I have this:

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);
    mContext = this;
}
```

`mContext` is a static `Context` for the entire class.

However even though I do that I cannot do this:

```
mContext.findViewById(R.id.score_text);
```

it says it cannot resolve the method "findViewbyId"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mContext is a static Context for the entire class

Please remove this.

> What am I doing wrong?

`findViewById()` is a method on `Activity` and `Fragment`. It is not a method on `Context`.

Since you are calling `setContentView()`, your `onCreate()` method is in an activity, and so you just call `findViewById()`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.extra;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OtherActivity extends Activity {
  public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="msg";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.other);

    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.msg);

    tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE));
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Activities/Extras))

Comment: How would I call `findViewbyId()` from a static method?

Comment: @Roymunson: You wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are in activity, I think you can use findViewById directly.Like that:
 `findViewById` instead of `mContext.findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
mContext.findViewById(R.id.score_text);
```

with

```
findViewById(R.id.score_text);
```

activity has already a findViewById method